# Probability Limits

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

What is the probability limit of $\frac{\frac{1}{n}{\sum}_{i = 1}^{n} X_i}{\frac{1}{n}{\sum}_{i = 1}^{n} Y_i}$ where $X_1$, ..., $X_n$, $Y_1$, ...$Y_n$ both come from a distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$

I know that the probability limit of $\frac{1}{n}{\sum}_{i = 1}^{n} X_i$ is just $\mu$ from the law of large numbers, but how do you solve for this when its these two fractions on top of each other? Does a probability limit even exist?

Thank you

Comment: If $\mu \neq 0$ then the limit is $1$ almost surely (assuming that $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ are independent and independent of each other). .

Answer (score 1):

There I will assume, that $X_1, ... X_n, Y_1, ... Y_n$ are i.i.d.

In this case, your problem splits in two cases:

1. $\mu \neq 0$

Then $\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i}{\sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i}$ converges almost surely to $1$ by the Strong Law of Large Numbers.

2. $\mu = 0$

Then we have by CLT, that $\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$ converges in distribution to $N(0, 1)$. The same goes for $\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$. And because they are independent, we have that $\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i}{\sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i}$ converges in distribution to $Cauchy(0, 1)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  When you say it converges in distribution to Cauchy(0,1), is that the same as the probability limit?  In my notes, it says "convergence in distribution does not necessarily imply convergence in probability."

Comment: @Alex, no, convergence almost surely, convergence in probability and convergence in distribution are three different types of convergence. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables for more details.

Comment: @Alex, however, I doubt that for the case $\mu = 0$ with given information we can derive anything stronger than convergence in distribution.